# Questions and Answers Ruby on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m developing question and answers application, where a user attempts to answer questions, I am looking to define a custom method rather than doing coding in the controller methods, creating a separate method that can be called to check the answer the user submitted against the answers database table, where the question_id and the user_input is the same as the Answers database.

Can anyone guide me with where I am going wrong or is there a better approach to checking the user submitted input against the database and then inputting the submission into the database.

**Submissions form**

```
<%= form_for :submission :controller => :submissions :action => 'check_answer' do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :contnet, :value => '' %>
<%= f.submit 'Submit Answer' %>
<% end %>
```

**Submissions_controller**

```
def check_answer
  answer = Answer.find_by(question_id: params[:question_id][:content])
  if answer.present?
    #insert into submissions table, display correct and add to scoreboard
  else
    redirect_to competitions_path
  end
end
```

**Answers Table :**

```
  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

**Question_table :**

```
 create_table "members_questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "point_id"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "file_file_name"
    t.string   "file_content_type"
    t.integer  "file_file_size"
    t.datetime "file_updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: You could just have a boolean field on answers called "correct" and mark which answers are correct, then you will know when the answer is submitted if it is correct or not at that point instead of running a check.  This solution is based on the assumption the user is selecting answers being presented to them.

Comment: Also watch out it looks like you have a typo in your submissions form, it says "cotnent" instead of "content".

Comment: Hi @RockwellRice, thank you for the response, the user will be inputting their own answers and it will be presented to them,  I thought by using a find_by or a where, It would return as a boolean, true/false if the answer exists? no? Would it be better to use a where function instead of a find_by?